# Why doesn't $\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\eta(s)$ approach $\frac{-1}{2}$ as $s$ approaches $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function), an equation which extends the Riemann zeta function from $Re(s)>1$ to $Re(s)>0$ is [an extension of the Riemann zeta function using the Dirichlet eta function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syhMb.png)

However, when I plot the function using only real arguments on [Desmos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpWBd.png), the function seemingly approaches $0$ as $x$ approaches $0$, which seems to contradict the statement that $\zeta(0) = \frac{-1}{2}$, which is in the same article.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: The thing that I wanted to test is whether the value of the function would approach -(1/2) as the input approaches 0 (only considering real inputs and approaching from the postive reals), however based on Desmos, the value seems to approach 0 instead

Answer (score 2):

Close to zero
$$\zeta(s)=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}  \log (2 \pi )\, s+O\left(s^2\right)$$ Your formula, extended to infinity, gives $\large\color{red}{-}\zeta(s)$

Comment: you may consider to add more details

Comment: That doesn't answer my question though, my question was why the function doesn't approach -1/2 as x goes towards 0.

Comment: It does. Plot both

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is merely an artifact of the truncation of the infinite series. Indeed, let

$$ \zeta_N(s) = \frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}. $$

Below demonstrates the graph of $\zeta_N(s)$ and $\eta(s)$ for $N=1,4,9,16,\ldots,10000$:

[image: Simulation]

Indeed, the graph of $\zeta_N(s)$ *does* approach $\zeta(s)$ in the regime $s > 0$.

On top of this, $\lim_{N\to\infty} \zeta_N(s)$ converges only when $\operatorname{Re}(s)>0$, and in particular, it diverges when $s = 0$. Hence, the alternating behavior of $\zeta_N(0) $ cannot be used for any claim against the identity $\zeta(0) = -\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting! However, since the series converges only for any s which satisfies Re(s)>0, couldn't one use the following reasoning: let x be a real number greater than zero.  limx→0ζ(x)=-1/2